# She came home exhausted

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is it correct to say "She came home exhausted"?

Is it necessary to use the verb "to arrive" here?

Comment: It is correct to say "She came home exhausted" but more context is needed. It isn't usual to say "She arrived home exhausted" except perhaps after a long journey.